# How to insert multiple images into a single SQL Server cell (of type varbinary(MAX))?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to include a message record in a SQL Server database table by using a query.

The table includes columns like ID, SENDER ID, RECEIVER ID, MESSAGE, SENT_TIME. The message content includes two or more images (images only).

Is it possible to insert all images into a single cell of the table column? If possible how will be the insert query and the retrieve query?

If not what is the best way to insert this?

Comment: You don't ever want to stick multiple pieces of information into a single tuple (aka cell). This violates 1NF and is a serious pain to deal with. If you have messages and those messages can contain attachments you should have an attachments table. And in the attachments table would be one row for every attachment sent with a message.

Comment: It is possible. For example zip images and store the .zip file. But.. why?

Comment: varbinary is just binary data, so if you're going to pack a "message" with varying data in it, the "message" should contain the all the information needed. Image Count|Image1Len|Image1Data|Image2Len|Image2Data|.... ImageNLen|ImageNData, and that is assuming all messages follow the same format.

Comment: @Uueerdo then what should be the most appropriate data type to store an image in SQL server database?

Comment: @SeanLange then what should be the most appropriate data type to store an image in sql server database?

Comment: If you are going to store the actual file in the table then varbinary(max). But you might consider storing the image on disc and a file name in the database. Or possibly using filestream.

Comment: If you have to store images in the database use one row per imagine and a foreign key reference to a parent record. (As Sean has already said).

Comment: @NawodaDharmabandu You asked "what should be the most appropriate data type to store an image" ... but the issue people are pointing out isn't about the data type, it's about the idea of storing more than one thing in the same cell. That's not something you should ever do in a relational database. You will just create problems for yourself. The very first comment in this thread should answer everything you need to know. And you should really study database normalisation and foreign key relationships before you start designing databases.

Answer (score 0):

use base64, concatenate the strings and a second field to store the lengths of the strings (comma separated or something with each length). then when you pull, you split the base64string from the lengths you saved. As Stated, not the best way, but answers the OP. You would use a varchar(max) in this instance